# How to Display Multiple Spaces in Redmine

Tags: redmine

I want to keep the hierarchy of an article.

In Redmine, all multiple spaces are replaced by 1 space

How to preserve those spaces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does not keep spaces:

```
h3. Directories where it exits

Root
    Child1
    Child2
```

Add a single space at the **Root** level will keep the hierarchy

This keeps spaces:

```
h3. Directories where it exits

 Root
    Child1
    Child2
```

Answer (score 8):

I think this way is efficient and controllable, just like the html code,use this instead a whitespace:

```
&nbsp;
```